# How to use GroupBy and OrderBy at the same time in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Am trying to query messages and group them by conversations and get the last message in each conversation, the structure of my table is

```
Table Messages(id(int), user_from(varchar), user_to(varchar), message(text), read(bool), chat_id(int), created_at(time_stamp), updated_at(time_stamp))
```

After searching for quite sometime here is what i think may solve my problem but i dont know how to implement this in Laravel 5.5 with eloquent or Query Builder

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id IN(
        SELECT MAX(id)
            FROM messages
            GROUP BY chat_id
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while and you must have a solution for it. But I met a similar problem and just spent over 1 hour on it, so I think it worthy to confirm the solution here.

Yes, using `Max` could deal with the situation here. I used query builder, it could be like:

```
DB::table('messages')
->selectRaw('max(id) as id, chat_id')  // you may add other fields
->groupby('chat_id')
->orderby('id')  // you may use other fields to sort
->get();
```